# How to embed several animated matplotlib graps into Qt

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt

I have developed a monitoring system that monitors the voltages and currents of a particular device. I have set my UI up using threading, offloading all the data searching and number crunching to a worker thread to keep the main thread free so the UI can constantly be updated. I set the system to update all the numerical values once a second. This is working just fine.

I now want to add a line graph that dynamically updates every 1 second (as soon as new data comes in) and be able to show 30-60 seconds of previous values. But this graph must also be embedded within my UI and also must not stop other elements in my UI from updating.

I have been able to get a static graph to be embedded in my program no issues, I am just wondering how I could extend this to be dynamic.

A shortened version of my code looks like this

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore # Import the PyQt4 module we'll need
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, SIGNAL
import sys # We need sys so that we can pass argv to QApplication

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

from design import Ui_MainWindow # This file holds our MainWindow and all design related things
              # it also keeps events etc that we defined in Qt Designer


class worker_thread(QThread):
    # all the number crunching goes in here with signals going back to the main thread

class Monitor(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.exit_button.clicked.connect(exit)
    #all the monitoring starts as soon as I hit the start button
        self.ui.go_button.clicked.connect(self.start_monitoring)
        self.ui.print_button.clicked.connect(self.test_print)

    def test(self,fig):
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        self.ui.mplvl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.draw()

    ...

def main():
    fig1 = Figure()
    ax1f1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
    ax1f1.plot(np.random.rand(5))

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    myapp = Monitor()

    myapp.test(fig1)

    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In the code you show there is only one matplotlib plot present. I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but what exactly prevents you from using a second plot in the exact same way as the first one? I think it would help to show us a code that reflects the subject of the question of having two plots. You may then specifically ask about the problem you face when updating the second plot.

Comment: Hello, that matplotlib is just a static plot of random data. I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to make it update with new data every second

Comment: As I said, the idea is to update the second plot exactly the same way you update the first one.